# App groupings disappear after every reboot (may be problem in the renaming home folder)

Tags: home-directory

Ubuntu 22.04 TLS. I group some applications (e.g. LibreOffice apps to one folder: Office) but after reboot I see this apps ungrouped again.
I bought my computer with preinstalled Ubuntu and already created "user". But after some time I decided to rename this name (e.g. myuser) and accordingly the home folder to /home/myuser.
May be problem in that fact? Because I created another user for my wife and I don't see such problem. But I don't want to create another one user and set settings again.
Or may be there is a solution to migrate all settings to a new user. But I think the error can migrate too).

Comment: also may be the reason not in renaming but in some other fact because my wife's account doesn't have any extensions installed nor any some specific actions created.
But I remember that I didn't touch settings simmilar to group apps in the app list).

Comment: Indeed, you pinpointed your problem. Of course, you can migrate settings, but as you say, you then risk migrating the settings. Your best bet will be to create a new account (delete the old first, then the new one again may have uid 1000) at this time, then make sure you use the proper tools and procedures to do system changes.

Comment: @vanadium, thank you. But I think it's too complicated way, because I need to reboot the computer all time after every change or I can come to situation like this ).

Comment: Feel free to think it is too complicated. Personally, I think it will be even more complicated  to pinpoint the issue on your particular system from a distance.

Comment: @vanadium, I did what you adviced). Thank you! Only it helped. Good luck!

Comment: Good it worked. You may want to delete your question now, because it is unlikely to be of help to other users.

Comment: @vanadium, I think it's not a good idea. Because it could help someone. When I search similar question I found the same question via my searcher (like Google), but there was neither a question, neither an answer.
Yes, there is not answer there but it saves the solution and time saving)).

Comment: Then provide the solution: write your answer, and you can even accept it (it is perfectly fine to write your own question and answer it yourself). The question alone is of no use, and the comments are not for archival purposes and may disappear anytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to tell who will want to find the solution to this problem because I found only deleted theme with approx the same question.
So the best way is not finding how we can fix it but better to create a new profile and copy settings what you need. For example, I copied only setting files only for Ubuntu Extensions but another options I set only by myself.

Thank you to @vanadium for this discussion.